# Find the largest three numbers in a row

Tags: google-sheets

Can anyone guide me in finding the three largest values, and sum them up in the column "I"?

And also need to highlight the top three values in each row.

[image]

For example, in this image, I want to find the largest three from D,E,F,G columns in each row and SUM of largest three should be filled in column "I".

Comment: If the numbers ae 99,99,99,50,50,20,10 do you want 99,99,99 or do you want 99,50,20 ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It is top 3, in your case it should be 99,99,99 only. Thanks

Comment: I can think of one simple formula, `=LARGE(D2:G2,1)+LARGE(D2:G2,2)+LARGE(D2:G2,3)`

Comment: @Davesexcel Great! Do you have any idea to exclude non numbers AND cell formatting??? However, give this as an answer. I'll upvote :)

Comment: I edited the formula, by cell formatting what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the large formula,
I'm sure there is a better way, but if there is an error you can use the iferror() so if there is an error the value will show up as 0.

=IFERROR(LARGE(D2:G2,1),0)+IFERROR(LARGE(D2:G2,2),0+IFERROR(LARGE(D2:G2,3),0))